# How to put saved photo into webpage through my written HTML

Tags: html

I have written a simple webpage on Notepad++ (it's not published, i'm just practicing) and I want to put a photo that I have saved in the page.  I have the photo saved in the same location as the notepad file.

I have tried `<img src="xxxxxxxxx\Lake.jpg"/>`

When I tried this, the only thing that showed up on the page is an extremely small white box with an x in the middle.  I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Your code isn't visible in your question. Edit it and show some code.

Comment: Such questions though. You could've easily picked up this problem if you went to w3school.com and checked how <img /> tags work.

Answer (score 1):

the right code is:

```
<img src="Lake.jpg"/>
```

In case you want to put the image in a subfolder, called for example images you need to set the src like this:

```
<img src="images/Lake.jpg"/>
```

See slash and not backslash

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work.  The photo is in a file called helpful-links_files.   so I have mg src="helpful-links_files/Lake.jpg"/> and it continues to give me the tiny white box with a  square through it

Answer (score 0):

To display an image in a src tag, you need to give the right path.

```
<img src="Lake.jpg" alt="Image of a lac"/>
```

Always give a relative path and not an absolute one.

```
<img src="relative/path/to/Lake.jpg" alt="Image of a lac"/>
```

Be a good citizen of the Internet and put some alt's in your tags.

Comment: I'm sorry I am very new to coding, what exactly even is an alt? and I just attempted it again, and It did not work.  I am at working using a desktop here, do I need to include the entire path? Using the entire path did not work and neither did starting with which drive it was in. Sorry that these are very dumb questions to you I am sure but I have not been able to figure it out.

Comment: Ok I learned what an alt was, and I added one.  It still does not work.

Comment: If you put <img src="helpful-links_files/Lake.jpg" alt="lac"/> and it's not showing anything, try this, in your web browser inspector, you can see in the network panel if your image is found or not by the browser.
If not it will display the content of the alt. So what do your inspector give you back, like a 404 or something ?